# Getting 'dns server not authoritative for zone' error when using aspnet_regiis -i

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7, dns, aspnet-regiis.exe

I am trying to get a .NET 4.5.1 asp.net app to run on my company computer (Windows 7 Enterprise) for the first time. Visual Studio told me to configure ASP.NET to use .NET 4.5. When I issued `aspnet_regiis -i` in an admin command prompt, the command displayed a "server not authoritative for zone" message. One suggestion I found was to run   `sfc /scannow` for possible corruption. It reported no issues found. I rebooted too.

The machine has a bunch of servers in its DNS Suffix Search List. I don't think that makes a difference.

I am unable to run the app using IIS Server as it gives an error message "Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list". Possible cause: Managed handler is used; however, ASP.NET is not installed or is not installed completely.
The site runs fine under IIS Express.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specifically used the one in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe and it worked. It seems just running aspnet_regiis.exe in a command prompt uses a version that doesn't work properly.